# Find the value of $\frac{\sum_{k<\frac n2} (n-2k){n \choose k}}{2^n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

$$
{{\sum_{k<\frac{n}{2}}(n-2k){n \choose k}} \over {2^{n}-1}}
$$

This problem should be solved using the Vandermonde Identity. But I am not able to solve it. I don't understand how to apply the identity to solve this problem. Are there any other ways to solve this problem ?

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format the equation. I made a draft of the expression, so please correct it if it's wrong.

Comment: I skimmed [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).  Then, I manually set $n$ to $6$ (computation = 60/63) and $7$ (computation = 140/127).  Assuming that I've made no mistake, I fail to see how Vandermonde's identity can be used here.  Please do **not** respond to this comment with a comment.  Instead please respond by editing your query.  Questions (1) Is the current editing of the query accurate? (2) What is the background of the problem.  Who suggested that Vandermonde's Identity pertains? ...see next comment

Comment: (3) What manual investigation have you made?  Does your computation at $n=6$ and $n=7$ agree with mine?  What are your thoughts on the problem?  What is your number theory background?  Which specific math class &/or math book (if any) is the source of the problem?  What is the exact wording (with full details) of the problem that was presented to you?

Comment: Is it $ \displaystyle \frac{1}{2^n - 1}  \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} (n-2k) {n\choose k}$? Did you want to say upper limit of $k$ is floor of $n/2$?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A100071

Answer (score 0):

I am ignoring $\frac{1}{2^n-1}$ for now. We can add that back in the final result.

$ \displaystyle \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} (n-2k) {n\choose k} = n\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} {n\choose k} - 2\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} k{n\choose k}$

$= n\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} {n\choose k} - 2n\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} {n-1 \choose k-1}$

If $n$ is odd,

$= \frac{n}{2} \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k} - n\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} {n-1 \choose k-1} + n {n-1 \choose {\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}}$

$= \frac{n}{2} \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k} - n\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose k} + (n - {\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}) {n \choose {\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}}$

$ = ({\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} + 1) {n \choose {\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} + 1}$

$ = m {n \choose m} \, \,$ where $m = {\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} + 1$

If $n$ is even,

$= \frac{n}{2} \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k} + \frac{n}{2} {n \choose {\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}} - n\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose k}$

$= \frac{n}{2} {n \choose {\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}} = (\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor + 1) {n \choose {\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}+1}$

$ = m {n \choose m} \, \,$ where $m = {\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} + 1$

So your answer is $\displaystyle \frac {m {n \choose m}}{2^n - 1} \,$ where $m = {\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} + 1$